# Using higher order functions to assess Boolen function and return tail

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a `foldr` function that evaluates a `Bool` function and, if it returns `True`, the return is `tail xs`. I intend to only remove the FIRST element only if the argument function returns `True`. Is there a way to change `foldr` (I can also use `map` and/or `filter`) to return `tail` in the instance of a `True`?

Here are two conditional functions I've been using:

```
isNegative = (<0)
isPositive = (>0)
```

This is a recursive function that checks to find if there's any `True` statement within the function but it removes the element where the `True` occurs instead of just returning `tail xs`:

```
 filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
 filterFirst x xs = foldr condition (\x -> []) xs True
    where
    condition y ys True
       | x y = y : ys True
       | otherwise = ys False
    condition y ys False = y : ys False
```

Would it be possible to use this but alter it to only remove the FIRST element? Or do I need an entirely different approach?

`filterFirst` should return:

```
filterFirst isNegative [1,2,(-3)]
[2,-3]

filterFirst isPositive [1,2,(-3)]
[2,-3]
```

Actually returns:

```
filterFirst isPositive [1,2,(-3)]
[1,2]
```

because it's filtering the first instance of `True` when I only want to remove the FIRST element in the entire list.

I HAVE to keep the function definition the same and I can use library functions but ONLY map, filter, and foldr higher order functions to solve this. I've been working on this forever and I feel just as lost as when I started.

Comment: What do you mean "you have to keep the function definition the same"? Also be sure to compile with -Wall. You can do `:set -Wall` in ghci and reload to get warnings

Comment: I can't change `filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`

Comment: @Francis That is not the function definition, that's the function's type.

Comment: yes, it is possible. you only need to replace one instance of a four letter word with another, five letter word. this assumes that your test results are actually wrong in one case.

Comment: have you been able to find it? would you like a further hint, or an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should be able to state our problem clearly without leaning on input/output examples. You don't have a clear problem statement, so let's start there. Here's how I would state what I think you want to do:

> `filterFirst` takes a predicate and a list. If *any* elements of the list match the predicate return the tail of the list, otherwise return the input list. When the input list is empty, return the empty list.

This isn't a great name for the function we've just described, but we'll leave it.

Here's a framework to get you started:

```
filterFirst p [] = [] -- "When the input list is empty, return the empty list."
filterFirst p l@(_:xs) = 
  if all p l
    then xs -- "return the tail of the list"
    else l  -- "...otherwise return the input list"

all :: -- type left as an exercise
all p l =
  -- try using `foldr` with `&&` here. 
  -- Then if you have time see if you can get it to return `False` on an infinite list.
  -- if you get stuck, try using `filter`, `map`, `==` and `length` to implement this.
```

Comment: they mean `f p (splitAt 1 -> first (filter (not . p)) -> uncurry (++) -> x) = x`, coded with `foldr`, `map` or `filter` *only*. this is my best guess anyway, they've asked about this problem before, several times recently, every time in a very confusing manner.